# Centering a QIcon in a QTableWidgetItem in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtablewidgetitem, qicon

I have a QTableWidget in which some of the QTableWidgetItem's contain a single QIcon (not a button, not clickable, just an image). Can anybody advise me on how to center the icon? 
I am providing below some sample code which correctly displays the icon, but  fails to center it (setTextAlignment seems to work for the items that contain text but apparently not for icons).

```
status_item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
status_icon = QtGui.QIcon()
status_icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(icon_file), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
status_item.setIcon(status_icon)
self.ServiceTableWidget.setItem(row, 0, status_item)
self.ServiceTableWidget.item(row, 0).setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter) #not working
```

I have also tried using the QIcon.paint() method, which did not work, although I may be implementing it incorrectly:

```
status_icon.paint(QtGui.QPainter(), QtCore.QRect(), QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried `AlignCenter` in `setTextAlignment`?

Comment: @SvenKrüger yes, that gives the same result (code runs and does not crash, but the icon is not centered)

Comment: Icons are normally placed in the left of a cell. How wide is your cell in relation to the icon? Is it much wider?

Comment: @A.E.Janett Do you want all the icons to be centered or only the icons of a certain row or column? In my answer all the icons will be centered

Comment: @eyllanesc I want all the icons to be centered. Thank you very much! I'll review your response and provide an update soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a delegate:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class IconDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
        super(IconDelegate, self).initStyleOption(option, index)
        if option.features & QtWidgets.QStyleOptionViewItem.HasDecoration:
            s = option.decorationSize
            s.setWidth(option.rect.width())
            option.decorationSize = s

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.ServiceTableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(3, 3)

        delegate = IconDelegate(self.ServiceTableWidget)  # <--- 
        self.ServiceTableWidget.setItemDelegate(delegate) # <---

        icon_file = "lamp.png"
        status_item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        status_icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        status_icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(icon_file), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        status_item.setIcon(status_icon)
        self.ServiceTableWidget.setItem(0, 0, status_item)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.ServiceTableWidget)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()
    if app is None:
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]